# Liferay Log override

Tags: java, logging, liferay

i want override the interface Log, because i use always this menssage:

```
private final static Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(classess.class);

log.error("La cita " + cita.getIdCita() + " ha producido un excepcion en " + e.getClass() + " casuda por "
                        + e.getCause() + ". Trace: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
```

my idea is override log.error for get in for parameter the throwlable only and then print the message but i don't know how call to original error.

Comment: This looks like custom code where you can do whatever you want anyway... I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve - do you intend to change the message, loglevel, configure the logging subsystem? What do you mean with "call the original error"?

Comment: i want say that i have the throwlable and send it to a class Log edited for me, that class receives for paramters the throwlable and this method call to log.error with the throwlable and mi menssage

Comment: i think that i have override the interface Log for that can output the menssage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to introduce a new method (with 4 parameters) to the Log interface. This is *completely* discouraged, as your new interface would be utterly incompatible with the assumption that anybody else makes when using this interface (or when providing alternative implementations). You would basically maintain your own private fork of Liferay, largely incompatible with the rest of the world. And that only for a change in a lowly Log class.

Don't go there. It's not too bad to construct an error message like you do in the snippet that you include in your question.

If you have the same thing duplicated everywhere in your code and think it would be cleaner otherwise, encapsulate Liferay's logging within your own logging class and use that, delegating to Liferay's log in the end.

However, don't invest too much time in fancy logging. IMHO that problem has been tackled once and forever, and within an application context, you'd not be able to deliver significant enhancement to the logging world...